# HTML download linking

Tags: html, linker, download

I got this file on my site calld BattleX.air, Now when you click on it on my site you get all weird drawings. 
Here: http://xedus.nl/download/BattleX.air

i tried `<a href="download/BattleX.air">` but it wont download. just show some random text
How can i fix this?

Comment: Zip the file and link to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your server so that it knows about `.air` files. It is claiming:

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Your browser is therefore trying to render it as plain text.

I don't know what the correct MIME type for this file format is. If there isn't an official one you should use `application/octet-stream`.

The specifics of how to configure your server will depend on the server you are using. On many *NIX platforms you can edit the file `/etc/mime.types`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [these instructions](http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm). Essentially, you need to set `Content-Disposition: attachment;` in your PHP header, in addition to setting the `Content-Type`.